# Is there a module for Drupal 7 to reset passwords for all users

Tags: email, drupal-7

Is there a module for Drupal 7 to reset passwords for all users. Same time it must send them email with new password or even better- link to create new one by them self.

There are some modules out there what I found but not doing what I need. For example http://drupal.org/project/account_reminder

I am starting to think that I have to write one by myself. Maybe combaining answer  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27768/how-can-i-programmatically-reset-a-users-password and module http://drupal.org/project/account_reminder

Any other thoughts?

Comment: definitely interested in this. I wonder if Rules could pull it off?

Comment: Agreed, I have the perfect use case for this at the moment also.

Comment: Too sad that I haven't made this into plugin. I ended up not needing to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer because this question popped up in a google search for mass password reset

The module mass password change module https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_password_change does what you want.

This module adds a views bulk operation action to reset the passwords of selected users that you can use in a custom view or admin view

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at : http://drupal.org/project/force_password_change

I haven't tested yet but the description seems to define your needs.

wish helps,

Cheers,